# time efficient algorithm for lcm of two numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, function

program 1:

```
def compute_lcm(x, y):
   if x > y:
       greater = x
   else:
       greater = y

   while(True):
       if((greater % x == 0) and (greater % y == 0)):
           lcm = greater
           break
       greater += 1

   return lcm
```

program 2:

```
def compute_gcd(x, y):
   while(y):
       x, y = y, x % y
   return x


def compute_lcm(x, y):
   lcm = (x*y)//compute_gcd(x,y)
   return lcm
```

Question:

program 2 is time efficient and program 1 exceeds time limit. how? both seems to be O(n). how can this be?

Comment: Program 1 is terrible.  Incrementing the larger of the two by one each time is close to trial-and-error.  Very slow.  Program 2 is a much more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 2 is not `O(n)`.

Approach 2 is known as the Euclidean Algorithm.

Gabriel Lamé in 1844 showed that the number of steps required for completion is never more than five times the number h of base-10 digits of the smaller number b.

Go through [it's efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency).